# Magento 2 Include custom JS in theme

Tags: magento2, jquery, magento-2.0, requirejs

I want to include custom js in my theme i put it in web/js path of theme

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\GWtheme\gw\web\js\jquery.flexisel.js
```

Then i created requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            clientrotate: 'GWtheme_gw/js/jquery.flexisel'
        }
    }
};
```

but when i check page source i can not see this js loading any where.

Also i tried other way as per below answer but it shows 404

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            clientrotate: 'GWtheme_gw/js/jquery.flexisel'
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "clientrotate"
    ]
};


"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/magento2/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/GWtheme_gw/js/jquery.flexisel.js"

Error: Script error for: GWtheme_gw/js/jquery.flexisel
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            clientrotate: 'GWtheme_gw/js/jquery.flexisel'
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "clientrotate"
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The require JS file just gives you access to the file when you call it into a template. But you still need to call the file into the head, use this file in your theme.

`{site-root}/app/design/frontend/{vendor-namespace}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"/>
    </head>
</page>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `js` via **requirejs** is the best way but not as you did

Here is a full example.

Supposing your js file is: `myfile.js`

> app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

> app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/web/js/myfile.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("Oooh yeah !");
       }
});
```

Now we have to load our js in phtml, supposing we want to call it in `yourfile.phtml`

> app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

If you want to load that js in all pages, you just have to do this:

> app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/myfile.js'
    ],
};
```

**Important:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` **CONTENT**
- clean `pub/static` **CONTENT**
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`